# how to make subscrip on gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I using an old version of gnuplot 4.2 in unix system without root privilege. I got a trouble of subscript, E_F which is not show in the Figure as: [image]

gnuplot

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color font "Times-Roman" 14
set encoding utf8
set term x11
set xlabel "x" offset -1, 0 
set ylabel "E_F" offset 0, 0
set title "x = 1" offset 0,-1
plot "total" u 11:10 w line ls 1 notitle
```

E_F

Comment: Try `set ylabel "E_F" offset 0, 0 enhanced`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Postscript (the language) does not handle utf8
2. x11 (the terminal) also does not handle utf8
3. You cannot set the terminal to both Postscript and X11 at the same time
4. The last supported release of gnuplot 4.2 was more than 10 years ago.
5. The good news is that after removing the `set encoding` and `set term x11` commands from your script, gnuplot 4.2.6 does produce a correctly formatted output file (screenshot below)[image]